# shoutcast streaming Flash AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, shoutcast

I have found a code on this site for shoutcast streaming in Flash AS3.
This is the code:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class NetConnectionExample extends Sprite {
        private var streamURL:String = "https://myHost:myPort";
        private var connection:NetConnection;
        private var stream:NetStream;

        public function NetConnectionExample() {
            connection = new NetConnection();
            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            connection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);
            connection.connect(null);
        }

        private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
            switch (event.info.code) {
                case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                    connectStream();
                    break;
                case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                    trace("Stream not found: " + streamURL);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function securityErrorHandler(event:SecurityErrorEvent):void {
            trace("securityErrorHandler: " + event);
        }

        private function connectStream():void {
            stream = new NetStream(connection);
            stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            stream.client = new CustomClient();
            stream.play(streamURL);
        }
    }
}


class CustomClient {
    public function onMetaData(info:Object):void {
        trace("metadata: duration=" + info.duration + " width=" + info.width + " height=" + info.height + " framerate=" + info.framerate);
    }
    public function onCuePoint(info:Object):void {
        trace("cuepoint: time=" + info.time + " name=" + info.name + " type=" + info.type);
    }
}
```

however I get this error when I compile the SWF:

Error opening URL 'https://myHost:myPort'
SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context.

can anyone please tell me how to do this correctly? I have been searching for two days now with no avail!!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The url simply doesn't exist, because that just a sample, but there are also some other problems with this code. For example: connection.connect(null), it won't connect to anywhere, so the netconnection instance won't dispatch netstatus event at all, that's why the connectStream method won't be executed.
If you want to play a stream from shoutcast, use this code:

```
    var soundOBJ : Sound = new Sound();
    soundOBJ.load(new URLRequest("http://78.159.104.147:80/"));
    soundOBJ.play( );
```

Choose a stream from here:
http://callear.org/radio-script/demo-flash/xxqpupruq/pickstream.php?id=1377200&title=TechnoBase.FM+-+24h+Techno%2C+Dance%2C+Trance%2C+House+and+More+-+128k+MP3+-+a+SHOUTcast.com+member+station

(simply replace the url in the constructor of the URLRequest)

Cheers

Tamas Gronas

Comment: This method is subject to serious memory leaks.  Try this on a low memory device and crash it in minutes.  Or, let it run for a couple hours on a high bitrate stream, and watch it eat all the RAM on your PC.